# Implement panning while keeping nodes draggable in d3 force layout

Tags: javascript, d3.js, drag, force-layout, pan

I use the `d3.layout.force` to visualize graph structures.
And I want both node dragging feature and panning feature.
(By 'panning', I mean something like google maps behavior.)

As shown in several d3 examples, nodes can be made draggable by `nodes.call(force.drag)`.
And panning can be implemented by `d3.behavior.drag`.

However, it seems they can not be used simultaneously.

Here is a code example:

```
var width = 400, height = 300;
var svg = d3.select('body').append('svg').attr({width: width, height: height});

var nodes = [{}, {}, {}, {}];
var links = [
    {source: 1, target: 0},
    {source: 2, target: 0},
    {source: 0, target: 3}
];

var nodeSel = svg.selectAll('circle')
    .data(nodes).enter().append('circle')
    .attr('r', 10).attr('fill', 'black');
var linkSel = svg.selectAll('line').data(links).enter().append('line')
    .attr('stroke', 'black');

var force = d3.layout.force()
    .size([width, height])
    .nodes(nodes).links(links)
    .linkDistance(80)
    .charge(-300)
    .on('tick', function() {
        linkSel
            .attr('x1', function(d) { return d.source.x; })
            .attr('y1', function(d) { return d.source.y; })
            .attr('x2', function(d) { return d.target.x; })
            .attr('y2', function(d) { return d.target.y; });
        nodeSel
            .attr('cx', function(d) { return d.x; })
            .attr('cy', function(d) { return d.y; });
    });

nodeSel.call(force.drag);


/* This block of codes spoils force.drag */
/* ****************************************
var drag = d3.behavior.drag();
var viewBoxX = 0, viewBoxY = 0;
drag.on('dragstart', function() {
    console.log('new dragstart is called');
}).on('drag', function() {
    viewBoxX -= d3.event.dx;
    viewBoxY -= d3.event.dy;
    svg.attr('viewBox', [viewBoxX, viewBoxY, width, height].join(' '));
}).on('dragend', function() {
    console.log('new dragend is called');
});
svg.call(drag);
**************************************** */


force.start();
```

(Working one is on jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/dersinces/hzL8T/1/.)

This code enables only node dragging, and not panning.
Activating a code block at bottom (line 36) enables panning but it makes nodes undraggable.

How can I implement graph panning while keeping nodes draggable?

Comment: You only need the zoom behaviour (it also does the dragging). See e.g. [here](http://jsfiddle.net/nrabinowitz/QMKm3/).

Comment: Thanks, @LarsKotthoff! I will have a look at `d3.behavior.zoom`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is how you can do it: [Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/hzL8T/4/)

The idea is to put the region which had the *draggable* behavior under the area which contains the nodes so that nodes can still receive mouseevents.

```js
// First append the area where the dragging will happen.
svg.append('rect')
  .classed('bg', true)
  .attr('stroke', 'transparent')
  .attr('fill', 'transparent')
  .attr('x', 0)
  .attr('y', 0)
  .attr('width', width)
  .attr('height', height)
  .call(drag);


// Then add the area which will contain the nodes.
var nodeArea = svg.append('g')
                 .classed('node-area', true);
```

Comment: The demo does not seem to solve my problem. Nodes are not draggable and panning does not work for links. Maybe your point is to insert invisible rectangle (same idea with @LarsKotthoff's example). But, that way panning is limited by size of the rectangle. I'd like another solution if possible.

Comment: Gah! Sorry about that. I linked to an older demo version. The version I have pointed to now should work.

Comment: Sorry to be late to reply, @musically_ut. Your new demo works perfectly! You solved my problem. Really thanks!